# WPF List of printers with icons

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make such combobox? [image: MicrosoftWord list of printers]
I know how to get the list of installed printers, but i cant find solution how to retrieve icons or determine difference between printer, fax or application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st solution (the easiest)**

You can change the array that you pass to the `GetPrintQueues` method.

```
LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();
EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes[] filters = new EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes[] {
    EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Fax
};
PrintQueueCollection printQueuesOnLocalServer =
    printServer.GetPrintQueues(filters);

foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueuesOnLocalServer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer: {0}", printQueue.Name);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

In this case I'm looking for Fax printers, but if I change the `filters` array I can search for something else.

**2nd solution (the most accurate)**

You can use `Win32_Printer` class (as JamesJGarner suggested), in this way

```
public void ListPrinters()
{
    string query = "SELECT * from Win32_Printer";
    ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject printer in managementObjectCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Printer Name: {0}", printer.Properties["DeviceID"].Value));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Attributes: {0}", Decode((UInt32)printer.Properties["Attributes"].Value)));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Dictionary<UInt32, string> decodeDictionary = new Dictionary<uint, string>();

private static Dictionary<UInt32, string> DecodeDictionary
{
    get
    {
        if (decodeDictionary.Keys.Count == 0)
        {
            decodeDictionary.Add(1, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_QUEUED");
            decodeDictionary.Add(2, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECT");
            decodeDictionary.Add(4, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT");
            decodeDictionary.Add(8, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED");
            decodeDictionary.Add(16, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_NETWORK");
            decodeDictionary.Add(32, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN");
            decodeDictionary.Add(64, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL");
            decodeDictionary.Add(128, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLEDEVQ");
            decodeDictionary.Add(256, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_KEEPPRINTEDJOBS");
            decodeDictionary.Add(512, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DO_COMPLETE_FIRST");
            decodeDictionary.Add(1024, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_WORK_OFFLINE");
            decodeDictionary.Add(2048, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_WORK_OFFLINE");
            decodeDictionary.Add(4096, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_RAW_ONLY");
            decodeDictionary.Add(8192, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_PUBLISHED");
            decodeDictionary.Add(16384, "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_FAX");
        }

        return decodeDictionary;
    }
}

private static string Decode(UInt32 value)
{
    List<string> attributes = new List<string>();

    foreach (UInt32 key in DecodeDictionary.Keys)
    {
        if ((value & key) == key)
        {
            attributes.Add(DecodeDictionary[key]);
        }
    }

    return String.Join(", ", attributes.ToArray());
}
```

The method `ListPrinters` prints a list of local pc printers with their own attributes.
You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the meaning of each attribute.

I just added the last attribute (i.e. "PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_FAX") which means that the printer is a fax.
In this way you can determine difference among printers.

Comment: Where did you take the value for Fax?

Comment: The attribute property of Win32_Printer class works as a C# enum marked with the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). So each value must be a power of two and `8192 * 2 = 16384`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

for icons I did it like this:

```
  If IsLocal And Not IsFax Then
                If .Standard Then
                    IconExtractor.Extract("imageres.dll", -49, True, eintrag.Bild)
                Else
                    IconExtractor.Extract("imageres.dll", -51, True, eintrag.Bild)
                End If
                .FriendlyName = obj.GetPropertyValue("Name")
            ElseIf IsLocal And IsFax Then
                If .Standard Then
                    IconExtractor.Extract("shell32.dll", -197, True, eintrag.Bild) 'sollte ok sein 197
                Else
                    IconExtractor.Extract("imageres.dll", -76, True, eintrag.Bild)
                End If
                .FriendlyName = obj.GetPropertyValue("Name")
            ElseIf Not IsLocal And IsFax Then
                If .Standard Then
                    IconExtractor.Extract("shell32.dll", -198, True, eintrag.Bild)
                Else
                    IconExtractor.Extract("shell32.dll", -199, True, eintrag.Bild)
                End If
                .FriendlyName = obj.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString.Replace(obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemName").ToString, "").Replace("\", "") & " on " & obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemName").ToString.Replace("\", "")
            Else
                If .Standard Then
                    IconExtractor.Extract("imageres.dll", -50, True, eintrag.Bild)
                Else
                    IconExtractor.Extract("imageres.dll", -53, True, eintrag.Bild)
                End If
                .FriendlyName = obj.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString.Replace(obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemName").ToString, "").Replace("\", "") & " on " & obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemName").ToString.Replace("\", "")
            End If
```

and for icons

```
Public Class IconExtractor
    Public Shared Function Extract(ByVal file As String, ByVal number As Integer, ByVal largeIcon As Boolean, ByRef Bild As ImageSource) As Boolean
        Dim large As IntPtr
        Dim small As IntPtr
        Try
            ExtractIconEx(file, number, large, small, 1)

            Bild = ToImageSource(System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(If(largeIcon, large, small)))
            
            DestroyIcon(small)
            DestroyIcon(large)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToImageSource(ByVal icon As Icon) As ImageSource
        Dim imageSource As ImageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
        Return imageSource
    End Function

    <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Shared Function ExtractIconEx(ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, ByRef phiconLarge As IntPtr, ByRef phiconSmall As IntPtr, ByVal nIcons As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="DestroyIcon")>
    Public Shared Function DestroyIcon(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```